# Is there a faster way to recolor text in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm very new to python and programming in general. I'm working on a tiny and ill-advised minigame involving a heatmap of space, using a text box in tkinter (if I weren't a week into this I would just use a different tool). Here's a video of what that looks like: [video](https://youtu.be/SERjCNs9M-s)

To recolor the text this way, I'm 1: building an array of text indexes for each heatmap value (the navy isn't currently used because I realized I can just make it the default text color but I've left it in)

```
#scans through each "pixel" in the viewport - translates values to the text I want displayed and records the index in the appropriate color group
        for y in range(20):
            for x in range(26):
                pix=viewarray[y][(x*2)-1]
                if pix != "/" and pix != "a" and pix != "b" and pix != "c" and pix != "d" and pix != "e" and pix != "f" and int(pix) >= 16:
                    pix = "/"
                pix = pix.replace("10","a")
                pix = pix.replace("11", "b")
                pix = pix.replace("12", "c")
                pix = pix.replace("13", "d")
                pix = pix.replace("14", "e")
                pix = pix.replace("15", "f")
                viewarray[y][(x * 2) - 1] = pix
                # if pix == "0" or pix=="1" or pix=="2" or pix=="3":
                #     navygroup.append(str(y+1)+"."+str((x*2)-1))
                if pix == "4" or pix =="5":
                    bluegroup.append(str(y+1)+"."+str((x*2)-1))
                if pix == "6" or pix =="7":
                    cyangroup.append(str(y+1)+"."+str((x*2)-1))
                if pix == "8" or pix =="9":
                    greengroup.append(str(y+1)+"."+str((x*2)-1))
                if pix == "a" or pix =="b":
                    yellowgroup.append(str(y+1)+"."+str((x*2)-1))
                if pix == "c" or pix =="d":
                    orangegroup.append(str(y+1)+"."+str((x*2)-1))
                if pix == "e" or pix =="f":
                    redgroup.append(str(y+1)+"."+str((x*2)-1))
                if pix == "/":
                    red4group.append(str(y+1)+"."+str((x*2)-1))
```

Then, inside the updating loop, tag_add and tag_configure are applied for each group:

```
                self.colortagger(tagname="bgroup", tagcolor="blue", array=bluegroup)
                self.colortagger(tagname="cgroup", tagcolor="cyan", array=cyangroup)
                self.colortagger(tagname="ggroup", tagcolor="#00FF00", array=greengroup)
                self.colortagger(tagname="ygroup", tagcolor="yellow", array=yellowgroup)
                self.colortagger(tagname="ogroup", tagcolor="#FFAA00", array=orangegroup)
                self.colortagger(tagname="rgroup", tagcolor="red", array=redgroup)
                self.colortagger(tagname="r4group", tagcolor="red4", array=red4group)

and elsewhere:

    def colortagger(self,tagname,tagcolor,array):
        global viewport
        for i in range(len(array)):
            self.viewport.tag_add(tagname, array[i])
        array.clear()
        self.viewport.tag_configure(tagname, foreground=tagcolor)
```

As seen in the video I shared, this slows down terribly if a lot of characters have to be recolored at once - it was even slower when all the navy characters were being recolored instead of just setting it as the default color - so I think that it must be something to do with how tag_add and tag_configure work? (there are a lot of for loops that scan through each individual character but none of them seem to slow it down this severely)

Is there a way to speed up this coloring? Or an alternate way to color select characters in a tkinter text box?

Comment: The easiest way to help you is when we can get a small executeble piece of code. Then we could experiment with your code and measure the time et cetera. Shrinking your code is a way to get faster. Also you may take a look on threading, to watch and change parallely.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but instead of calling `tag_add` once for every character, try grouping all of the indexes together so that you can call `tag_add` just once for each tag. Also, it doesn't appear that you remove old tags, so part of the problem may be that each character ends up with hundreds or thousands of tags over time. Are you removing all of the old tags before adding new tags?